# How to calculate customs duty on importing furniture to Switzerland?

Tags: switzerland

What custom duties and taxes must one pay on importing furniture into Switzerland from the European Union? I've heard that these are calculated based on weight. What are details of the calculation? How would I calculate the duties and taxes on say

- 100 kg of new furniture, worth 200 CHF

I am moving to Switzerland from the European Union next month. I understand that household effects older than six months [can be moved duty free](https://www.ezv.admin.ch/ezv/en/home/information-individuals/personal-property--students--holiday-homes--getting-married-and-/importation-into-switzerland/moving--household-effects-.html). I'm considering buying new furniture in my home country before I move. I'm curious what duties I would have to pay.

Comment: Are you moving to Switzerland to live? And where are you coming from?

Comment: thanks this is useful. I am a little confused with the additional tare, which has a charge per kilo. Is this applicable in all cases? Assuming the weight is 20 kilos and the fee is 15%, what is the calculation? 3 CHF?

Answer (score 3):

The actual procedures and duties may vary depending on how you import the furniture, i.e. yourself in your own vehicle, or have it transported by a mover. The mover should also be able to assist with the details.

You can find duties on [tares.ch](http://www.tares.ch) and explanations [here](https://www.ezv.admin.ch/ezv/en/home/information-companies/customs-tariff---tares.html).

There's a very detailed list of products, each with one or more rates. Most furniture-related tariffs I've seen have a 0 rate for imports from the EU, but I have definitely not checked all of them.

Note that the tariff is based on the country of origin, not necessarily where you actually bought the items.

You will also have to pay VAT at the prevailing rate (but you should be able to get a VAT refund in the country where you bought them, which will most certainly be higher).